# Creating non-trivial database on SQL Server on request

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am facing a problem with slow new database creation using 17000 lines of code long script sent from ASP.NET as a batch, in one command. Problem is that execution of this script takes 20s sometimes more during peak times. If I run this script in SQL Server Management Studio, it takes 2s.

What is the best practice to create databases on request, put script into a stored procedure, database cloning, pre-creation and than renaming of DB? We need to be sure it is compatible with concurrent environment under load.

Thank you.

Comment: Are all databases in this instance clones of each other? If so, the best method would be to add all the objects / data to the model database. Then all you have to do is issue a CREATE DATABASE command. The new database that gets created will be a copy of the model database. That's what the model database is for, it's a template (a model) for all new databases created on that instance.

Comment: Is there anything dynamic about the DB creation code that *requires* you execute it in a command? Or could you exec SQLCmd using the script file and other appropriate switches to create the DB?

Comment: Have you profiled your ASP.NET application to see where the additional 18s are being spent?

Comment: It is a legacy code and I just realized that SMO is used to call it and using profiler I can see that the script gets split into 1000s of separate call, so this is probably the problem. But what is the best approach to create DB on fly when user register new account?

Answer (score 0):

Sending 17000 lines over the wire to a SQL server seems like an awful amount of overhead and slow as all get out. So does using the SQL client for ASP.NET to do anything like this.

Yes, I am in favor of you using a stored proc to do this. Not too sure about the DB cloning and re-naming operation; I would bet you could get away from that by using parameters to your stored proc to define that.

Comment: Problem is that you have to store that PROC inside common DB and and PROC can't contain USE command, so ho could I create DB and run the script on newly created DB?